# How to put "Storage Spaces" in the Windows 8 start screen?

Tags: windows-8

If you search for "Spaces" in Windows 8 in the settings, there is an entry called "Storage Spaces". I'd like to save that as an icon I can click directly in the Start screen.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The secret is to locate the 'Storage Spaces' icon in the Control Panel, System and Security section.

Having located the icon, right-click and 'Pin to Start'  (Scroll to the right of the Metro-style UI to locate your icon)

Answer (score 0):

To create a shortcut to Storage Spaces:

1. Right click on an empty area on the desktop, and click on New and
   Shortcut.
2. Copy  `control.exe /name Microsoft.StorageSpaces` and click Next.
3. Name it Anything.

Now you can pin it to Start by right clicking.